# Volume of $ G:=\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb {R} ^3 | x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \le 1 , x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0\}$

Tags: integration

I'm searching for the volume for the set in the title. I've tried to use polar coordinates, but the solution gets really ugly (maybe I do something wrong), then I tried it by projecting it on the xy-plane, but by solving the integrals the solution gets again really ugly. Does somebody know an easy or trivial way for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

method is due to Dirichlet in 1839; the volume is
$$  \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^3 }{\Gamma \left( 2 \right)} = \Gamma \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^3 $$

My calculator thinks
$$ \Gamma \left( \frac{4}{3} \right) \approx 0.892979512 $$ so
$$ \Gamma \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^3 \approx 0.712072943 $$

Encouragement: note that this method, for the part of the unit sphere in the positive octant, gives
$$  \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^3 }{\Gamma \left( \frac{5}{2} \right)} = \frac{ \frac{1}{8} \pi^{3/2}}{ \frac{3}{4} \pi^{1/2}} = \frac{\pi}{6},$$
which is, well, correct.

Über Eine Neue Methode zur Bestimmung Vielfacher Integrale

Über eine neue Methode zur Bestimmung vielfacher Integrale p.381-390
Bericht über die Verhandlungen der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften. Jahrg. 1839, S. 18-25

near the middle of page 389 in the Werke http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k99435r/f402.item.zoom  with $a=b=c=1$

[image]

Comment: I'm not very schooled in using the gamma function, but that's really interesting and I appreciate that answer.